# How to build a larger ROM using smaller parts?

Tags: digital-logic, eeprom, rom

How can i build a 1024-bit ROM using 512-bit and smaller ROM's?
Is it good idea to use a 2:1 MUX and that selects on of 2 512-bit ROM's?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your ROMs have some kind of Chip Select pin, wire the address pins of the ROMs to the least significant address lines,  Then use some simple logic to monitor the more significant address lines, selecting the chip select pin on the correct ROM.

Answer (score 0):

Usually they use higher address bit to multiplex chip select line. Question is, don't you have a 1024 bit ROM?

Answer (score 0):

If the ROM has tristate outputs or all are common drain or all are common collector then you can bus the output pins together and use a decoder to enable the correct chip. Many ROMs have high impedance output states for exactly this purpose.

If the ouputs don't have a high impedance state then you can add an additional tristate buffer on each ROM chip where you pipe the enable signal from the decoder to the enable pin.

Otherwise you can indeed use a 2:1 mux on the output pins though that isn't as easy to expand.